# python customtkinter library - how to install

Tags: python, tkinter, import, package, customtkinter

I need to install the customtkinter package for python.

I used the command `pip install customtkinter` to install the package.
When running `pip list` I can see the `customtkinter` package version.

In the pycharm editor the package seam to get imported:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tal.d\PycharmProjects\py1.py\venv\1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import customtkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customtkinter'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure your pycharm is using the correct interpreter and enviornment.... [this might help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#view_list)

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.

```
pip3 install customtkinter
```

Update existing installation:

```
pip3 install customtkinter --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just pip install customtkinter. But first make sure you have pycharm configured properly. If other pip packages work, then this should work too.
Assuming that you have python 3, you need to open your command prompt and type in the following commands:

Install customtkinter:

```
pip3 install customtkinter
```

Install packaging:

```
pip install packaging
```

And then you should be able to use customtkinter by importing it into your program like other packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very question, what solved it was adding customtkinter in the preferences like you would add a theme.

`Settings (ctl+alt+s) --> Click your project on the left --->Click python interpreter ---> Click the "+" button ---> search 'customtkinter' --> click install`

After that it was just a matter of fixing my capitalization mistakes to get the program to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Anaconda and Python installed, you need to choose a global interpreter, i.e. not Anaconda 3. Switch the interpreter

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you ensure that you are using a virtual environment (Virtualenv). You will get the option when you create a new project in Pycharm. You should also at this point be able to select a base Python interpreter.

[image: Create Project (Pycharm)]

Click Create and then let Pycharm do its thing.

Next go to File -> Settings and expand the link to your project name (just below Version Control).

[image: Project Selection]

Now click *Python Interpreter* and you will see a display which includes the installed modules (you should see pip listed and a couple of others). Above the list of modules is a + icon.

Click that and a popup will appear. Enter customtkinter into the search field at the top. You should see the module listed. Select it with your mouse and then click the Install Package at the bottom of the dialog.

[image: Adding Packages]

Keep an eye out for any errors.

Once the package is installed you should be good to go.

You can also check the venv directory, which sits in your project folder. If you drill down from there "venv > lib > PythonX.YY > site-packages", you should see a customtkinter folder. I think that on Windows, the PythonX.YY is not included in the path, so that would be something like:

"venv > lib > site-packages"

Oh and as suggested in another reply, I would avoid Anaconda. It seems there might be some issues there, when it comes to CustomTkinter.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do

```
python3 -m pip install customtkinter
```

alternatively you can use

```
pip3 install customtkinter
```

instead of

```
pip install customtkinter
```